# Why does my javascript and css styling for jquery mobile only sometimes load?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I was wondering why my jquery mobile styling only sometimes loads only if when I press the refresh button before I hit the next link named Sign up.

If I were to hit the back button and then hit the sign up button again without refreshing, the list that would appear would look totally different without the jquery styles.

I am just baffled as to what is going on.

Here is the Link:
http://71.162.197.6/iGotChu/www/

And if you want to see what it is on jsfiddle here it is: `enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/ayz8sd6u/

****Sadly, the problem doesn't show up on jsfiddle. The list I am trying to print doesn't even show up after you press sign up.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>changePage JSON Sample</title>

<link rel="stylesheet"     href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
<!-- Default Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">
<script src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>



     <script>






    $(document).ready(function(){$('form').on('submit', function() { 
        var pageRequest = "" + $(this).attr('action');
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(),    function(data,status){
            //alert("Returned data: " + data);
            pageRequest = parsePhp(pageRequest);
            pageHandler(pageRequest, data);
        });
return false;
    });
    });
function parsePhp(pageRequest){
    var index1 = pageRequest.lastIndexOf("/");
        index1++;
        //alert(index1);
        var index2 = pageRequest.lastIndexOf(".");
        //alert(index2);
        var page = pageRequest.substring(index1,index2);
        //alert(page);
        return(page + "");
}


//Owl Carousel
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu").owlCarousel({
        singleItem: true,
    });
    return(false);
});

</script>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
    var at = $("a").attr("href");
    $("a").click(function(){
            //alert("the Attribute is: " + at);

            var print = "";
            for (i=0;i<10;i++){
                print = print + "<ul data-role='listview'><li><a     href='index.html'><img src='images/album-bb.jpg' /><h3>Broken Bells</h3>      <p>Broken Bells</p></a></li></ul>";
            }
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = print;

            $.mobile.changePage($(attribute),"slide");  
        }
        );
});




 function pageHandler(pageRequest, result){
    result = result + "";
    if(pageRequest == "register"){
            alert("Your account as been created!");
            $.mobile.changePage($("#loginPage"),"slide");
            }
    else if(pageRequest == "login"){
        alert("result data: " + result);
        if(result == "success"){
            $( ".loginPopUp" ).popup( "open");
            $.mobile.changePage($("#home"),"slide");
        }
        else{
            alert("Incorrect Credentials");
        }
    }
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="loginPage">
<div data-role="header">
      <h1> iGotYou! </h1>
</div>
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<form method="post" action="http://71.162.197.6/iGotChu/php/login.php">
  <div class="ui-field-contain">
    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="passWord"  placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">     
  </div>
 </form>
 <a href="#createAccountPage" data-role="button">Sign Up</a>

</div>
 </div>



<div data-role="page" id="createAccountPage">
 <a data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-role="button">Create Account</a>
 <form method ="post" action ="http://71.162.197.6/iGotChu/php/register.php">
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="User Name">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
    </div>
  </form>
  <div data-role = 'content'>
 <div class='content-primary' id = 'test'>

</div>
</div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please recreate your problem in jsfiddle. Nobody will click the link... especially not when  "I GOT CHU" is part of the url.

Comment: LOL! You have a point there

Comment: I am trying to recreate the problem but it doesn't seem like the list with the problem  even loads on jsfiddle.

Comment: I am trying to print elements in a list 10 times however, on js fiddle it won't even load, and on my server it would sometimes load the list with the correct styling and other times not.

Comment: You won't be able to see the problem in jsfiddle, but this is it on jsfiddle.      http://jsfiddle.net/ayz8sd6u/

Comment: check you paths to the files you want to load. Also empty your browsers cache if you made changes to style sheets. I'm afraid I can't help you if the problem is not reproducible in jsfiddle and without code example.

Comment: I think my file paths are right. I'll try to give you some code.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache? Has it cached some older version of your style/script that only seems to reload intermittently?

Comment: Looking on the javascript console, the only problem seems to be is that cordova is not available because I am intending this to be a mobile application and that the jpeg file is miss. Yet, that shouldn't affect if a style is intermittent or not should it?

Comment: Cleared the cache on google chrome, still sadly no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time any page is loaded in Jquery, the page is "CREATED" and is only created once and then saved into memory.
Using the "pagebeforecreate" event listener, I can change the html before the page is created. In the API, the "pagebeforecreate" interrupts the page loading before the jquery enhancements are performed, thus, the html is injected, and then the enhancement scripts can then do their work in orderly fashion.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate",function(event){
//alert("page before created activated");
var nextPage = event.target.id;
  var print = "";
            if (nextPage=="createAccountPage"){
                $.ajax({
                  url: '<your server>',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  async: true,
                  success: function(data) {
                    var print = "";
                    for (i=0;i<data.firstName.length;i++){
                        print = print + "<li><a href='index.html'><img src='images/album-bb.jpg' /><h3>"+data.firstName[i]+ " " + data.lastName[i] + "</h3><p>Broken Bells</p></a></li>";
                        } 
                        $("#usersList").html(print);
                        print = "";
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

However, the problem is not totally fixed as one would need to refresh the html if it were ever to be changed due to a caching problem where the old page would be saved and the html would not be reloaded even though an ajax call is made. This goes hand in hand with my earlier statement that pages are created only once. To force a reload/notify that the page has been changed, I made a complementary scheme that upons an ajax call, the html is updated with the function

```
$('#usersList').listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where to start here, but I think what you're having issues with is in your loop. Try something like this:

```
$("a").click(function () {
    var printHtml = "<ul data-role='listview'>";
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printHtml += "<li><a href='index.html'><img src='images/album-bb.jpg' /><h3>Broken Bells</h3><p>Broken Bells</p></a></li>";
    }
    printHtml += "</ul>";
    $("#test").html(printHtml);
    $.mobile.changePage($(attribute), "slide");
});
```

You're printing a new `<ul>` each time and I don't think you need to do that.

Comment: You're right, I don't have to print it every time but it doesn't seem to make a difference after I made the changes.